# Area under ROC curve of large ff data frame

Tags: r, roc

Hi I am using the R libraries

```
library(pROC)
library(ff)
library(ffbase)
library(biglm)
```

and the following code to generate a logistic regression model using an ffdf large data frame and compute the area under the ROC curve:

```
mymodel <- bigglm(outcome~x1+x2+x3,family=binomial("logit"),data=myffdf,maxit=20)
summary(mymodel)
pred <- predict(mymodel,myffdf,type="response")
rocobj <- roc(myffdf$outcome, pred)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in opsff_compare_logic(x, y, "|") : 
operator requires length 1 for e2, recycling not possible
```

Thank you for any advice how to get the AUC.

Comment: This will work `roc(myffdf$outcome[], pred)` - note the square brackets

Comment: Good stuff. Would be good if you could write it as an answer (and accept it) or maybe @JVL could edit their answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work:

```
roc(myffdf$outcome[], pred)
```

Note the square brackets.

Thanks to user20650 and JVL

Comment: You've thanked yourself in there - I guess you meant user20650 ;)

Comment: LOL yes indeed. Hey I'm trying ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The function [`pROC::roc`](https://github.com/xrobin/pROC/blob/master/R/roc.R) tries to check for NAs in `myffdf$outcome` or `pred` using the following line:

```
nas <- is.na(response) | is.na(predictor)
```

But a glance at [`ffbase::opsff_compare_logic`](https://github.com/edwindj/ffbase/blob/master/pkg/R/Ops.R) reveals that an `ff_vector` object can only be compared to another `ff_vector` object or to a vector of length 1. So the error occurs because `myffdf$outcome` is an `ff_vector`, but `pred` is not and has length > 1.

A possible solution might be to call

```
rocobj <- roc(myffdf$outcome, as.ff(pred))
```

instead.

Comment: Thanks, but this gave the error: Error in roc.default(myffdf$outcome, as.ff(pred)) : 
  Predictor must be numeric or ordered. The solution above with brackets worked for me.

Comment: Sounds good. I'm guessing the brackets must cause it to be treated as a regular numeric vector rather than an `ff_vector`.

Comment: @user2557662 that's because `ff_vector`s are not supported by pROC. They cause other problems down the line, for example you can't call `split` and many other base functions on them.